# Listbox mousedown event returns previously selected item

Tags: vba, drag-and-drop, listbox

I am preparing a drag&drop solution for a number of listboxes. The problem is that when I click on an item in the list, Windows (or whomever) sets the item blue, fires the `mousedown` event, but both`.Selected()` and `.Listindex` methods handled within `mousedown` event handler return the previously selected item. By clicking on the (already blue) item again, they return the item correctly.

What happens is I click on an item keeping the mouse button pressed, the item gets blue, I drag it to the other listbox and the previously selected item gets there.

```
Private Sub pThisListBox_Mousedown(ByVal Button As Integer, _
           ByVal Shift As Integer, _
           ByVal X As Single, _
           ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim MyDataObject As DataObject
    Dim sSelected As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Effect As Integer

    If Button = 1 Then
        sSelected = vbNullString
```

Var #1

```
        For i = 0 To pThisListBox.ListCount - 1
            If pThisListBox.Selected(i) Then
                sSelected = pThisListBox.List(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Var #2

```
        With pThisListBox
            If .ListIndex >= 0 Then
                sSelected = .List(.ListIndex)
            End If
        End With
```

Common

```
        If LenB(sSelected) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set DragSource = pThisListBox
        Set MyDataObject = New DataObject
        MyDataObject.SetText sSelected
        Effect = MyDataObject.StartDrag
        Debug.Print sSelected
    End If

End Sub
```

I've already tried playing with `.MultiSelect`, it did not help. It is actually set to `fmMultiSelectSingle` but the ideal would be `fmMultiSelectMulti`. 
Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Did you try MouseMove instead of MouseDown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (also for multiselect)

```
Private Sub pThisListBox_MouseMove(ByVal Button As _
 Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As _
 Single, ByVal Y As Single)
 Dim MyDataObject As DataObject

 If Button = 1 Then
 Set MyDataObject = New DataObject
 Dim Effect As Integer
    For i = 0 To pThisListBox.ListCount - 1
            If pThisListBox.Selected(i) Then
                MyDataObject.Clear
                MyDataObject.SetText pThisListBox.List(i)
                Effect = MyDataObject.StartDrag
               End If
        Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, `MouseMove` is the right event for handling this. It works perfect. `MouseDown` fires before updating `.Selected` and `.Listindex`.

Comment: mouse_up works and is super easy to code, look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution is the right one.

If the event of mouse_down is too early, just go mouse_up event.

I Tried it, and it works. here is an exemple of code:

```
Private Sub Listbox_Mouseup(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Dim Bonus$, i&

i = Listbox.ListIndex
Bonus = Listbox.List(i, 0)

If Button = 1 Then      
      Me.Caption = Bonus
End If

End Sub
```

To not make it look strange, on mouse_down, i do `me.caption=""` .